# Naming camelcase function names containing camelcase brand names

Tags: naming-conventions

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.
>
> -- Phil Karlton

I'm having a function called isIos() which returns true if the device is iOS (this is a cordova app).

iOS is the correct brand syntax but the coding style implmented used camelcase for the function name.

Should the function name be:

`isIos()` or `isiOs()` or `isIOs()` or something else?

What is the recommended way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no general recommendation, your language might have guidelines that you might want to follow (doesn't seem the case with Node.js or javascript), or your company or application might have guidelines that you will have to follow, or there might be existing uses of the term in the application that you'll probably want to imitate, otherwise just use what seems easiest to read.

In this case, it might be `isIOS`, or `isIos`.

If you're using camel case though you should probalbly always put in upper case the first character of each word, `isiOs()` seems very confusing.

Your best option in these cases anyway is often to spare you the embarrassment and use a different name, if you can come up with one.

EDIT:
If you are not required to follow strict camel case you can also settle to is_iOS, which lets you keep the original case. This is probably the best alternative.